# Web api locking on a unique identifier level

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm implementing a CRUD service in Asp.net WebAPI that uses a pretty complicated data model; however, each data model object can be identified by a `Guid` type.
I would like to prevent actions from running concurrently for given `Guid`.

So, for example I can allow updates for `Object{ Guid = 1 }` and `Object{ Guid = 2 }` to run at the same time, yet I can't allow for two separate updates on `{ Guid = 1 }` to run at the same time. This second scenario might happen as similar requests from completely separate clients might come to the server.

How can I achieve this kind of locking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be possible to use a database?

Make a simple table with two columns: `Id (int)` and `InUse (bit)`.

You could even make it one column, just `Id (int)` - if an Id is in the table, it's in use.

This way, it would not be affected by app pool recycling as an in-memory solution would be and you can take advantage of transactions.

Comment: If a service dies (or is recycled) in the middle of long running transaction, how would I take this flag off?